# Program Closed when I Press Minimize

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 2 functions

```
private void Main_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
    {
        Hide();
        notification.BalloonTipTitle = "Smart Connection";
        notification.BalloonTipText = "Smart Connection has been minimized to the taskbar.";
        notification.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
    }
}
```

For my `Form` minimize, and

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (connected)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?",
               setting.Split(':')[0],
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
}
```

for my `Form` closing event

But when I press minimize button, `MessageBox` come and say "are you sure?"

For both yes and no button when I press any of them, the program is closed.

But why they are 2 different functions for 2 different events?

i find out why `this.Hide()` close my porgram its becuse of my splash form

here is my slash form

```
public partial class Splash : DevComponents.DotNetBar.Metro.MetroForm
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progress.Value += 2;
        if (progress.Value == progress.Maximum)
        {
            this.Hide();
            timer.Stop();
            Main f = new Main();
            f.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and my `Program.cs` is

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        bool createdNew;
        using (var mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "SmartConnection", out createdNew))
        {
            if (createdNew)
            {
                Application.Run(new Splash());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("some text");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms? Where are the event handlers wired up?

Comment: Check which functions are connected to the events.

Comment: @ChrisShain its windows Form app

Comment: @TobiasKnauss i checked them they are connected to their event

Comment: Set some breakpoints and debug your application step by step.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss today i just add one splash form to my app but i dont  think its becuse of the splash form

Comment: As I said: add breakpoints to the start of each function and check what is called in which order. If necessary, remove code to rebuild the last working state. Just do a comprehensive testing and debugging. Should be easy to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do "Find all references" on

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
```

My guess is it is wired up to more than just the FormClose X.

Edit: I tried your Closing event and when I click No it doesn't close so not sure why for you it still closes.

Comment: both of them have 1 references and it is pointing to their  event handler